# can't run my xamarin UI test project on iOS with mac

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

I want to run my xamarin ui test project on ios simulator with my mac

and i have missing references like in the picture :

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhkAX.png)

and when I try to run i'm getting this error :

```
OneTimeSetUp: System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
```

environment info:

- .net 4.6.1
- Xamarin.uitest 3.0.5
- xcode 10.0.3
- Nunit 3.12.0

Comment: Update the version of Xcode and Xamarin.UITest to the latest and try again .

Comment: didn't helped same error

Comment: I also updated all the Nuggets and it didn't helped

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT when will Xamarin.UITest support XCode 12 and iOS 14? that's the blocker

Comment: Check https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/1998 and https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/1992 . You could follow them .